# how to retrieve the files names and download few extension file from a ftp url?

Tags: python, urllib

I have a few URLs. From these URLs, I would like to get the '`.gbff.gz`' files name and download those files. I am using **python3** to get do this.

My plan is first to get the file .gbff.gz files and then use '`urllib.request.urlretrieve`' function to get the files from an URL. I can retrieve the file using below code but unable to get the .gbff.gz extension filenames. so can someone help me to get that?

Code to download the file from URL.

```
import os
import urllib.request


def download_file(path, url):
    url = url.rstrip()
    head, tail = os.path.split(url)

    filename = os.path.join(path, tail)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
    except urllib.request.URLError:
        print("Download Issue: {}".format(url))
    finally:
        print("Download Complete: {}".format(url))
        return filename
```

But somehow, I am getting some problem to retrieve the name.

Here is my try:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/010/065/GCF_000010065.1_ASM1006v1/"
result = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

pattern = re.compile('*.gbff.gz')
filelist = pattern.findall(result )
print(filelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are using is not correct, try `pattern = re.compile('.*\.gbff.gz')` instead.

Your regex is a "Unix shell-style wildcards"  expression, in regex the `*` has a different meaning: repeat the previous character 0 to `n` times. The previous character `.` matches every character except line break.

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern = re.compile(r'[\w.]*.gbff.gz') will match only filenames.